# UIScrollView scrolls on all the simulators but not on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiscrollview, ios8, xcode6

So after figuring out how scrollView works, I've implemented it with the following code:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
CGRect view = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 750);
self.scrollView.contentSize = view.size;
```

The above code works as intended on ALL simulators in Xcode 6. However, when I run it my phone (iphone4s on ios7), the scroll does not function at all. Are people experiencing the same problems since the new release? Or am I missing something I've learned from the documentation?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: Yes I am using AutoLayout, but not size classes.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you get it running on iOS7? Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Anil , I did not get it to run on iOS 7. I just updated everything to 8.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did not try Vishu's answer, but what I did was update to iOS 8 so it's compatible with Xcode 6 and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue here. Just need to resize the scrollview's frame size in viewDidLayoutSubviews which overrides auto layout.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2600)];

    // Adjust frame for iPhone 4s
    if (self.view.bounds.size.height == 480) {
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436); // 436 allows 44 for navBar
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the problem with AutoLayout-Size Classes, backward compatibility to iOS 7. This fix my no scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

***In AutoLayout***

In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin of the superview does not change the position of the view.

The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content view.

The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the scroll view. (This should not be confused with the intrinsicContentSize method used for Auto Layout.) To size the scroll view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must either be explicit regarding the width and height of the scroll view, or the edges of the scroll view must be tied to views outside of its subtree.

Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

Here are two examples of how to configure the scroll view, first the mixed approach, and then the pure approach

***Mixed Approach***

Position and size your scroll view with constraints external to the scroll view—that is, the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property is set to NO.

Create a plain UIView content view for your scroll view that will be the size you want your content to have. Make it a subview of the scroll view but let it continue to translate the autoresizing mask into constraints:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIView *contentView;



contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,contentWidth,contentHeight)];



[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
```

// DON'T change contentView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints,
// which defaults to YES;

// Set the content size of the scroll view to match the size of the content view:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth,contentHeight)];
```

/* the rest of your code here... */

```
}
```

Create the views you want to put inside the content view and configure their constraints so as to position them within the content view.

Alternatively, you can create a view subtree to go in the scroll view, set up your constraints, and call the systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: method (with the UILayoutFittingCompressedSize option) to find the size you want to use for your content view and the contentSize property of the scroll view

***Pure Auto Layout Approach***

To use the pure autolayout approach do the following:

Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on all views involved.
Position and size your scroll view with constraints external to the scroll view.
Use constraints to lay out the subviews within the scroll view, being sure that the constraints tie to all four edges of the scroll view and do not rely on the scroll view to get their size.
A simple example would be a large image view, which has an intrinsic content size derived from the size of the image. In the viewDidLoad method of your view controller, you would include code similar to the code shown in the listing below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIImageView *imageView;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary;

// Create the scroll view and the image view.
scrollView  = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

// Add an image to the image view.
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"MyReallyBigImage"]];

// Add the scroll view to our view.
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

// Add the image view to the scroll view.
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];

// Set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO so that the views autoresizing mask is not translated into auto layout constraints.
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Set the constraints for the scroll view and the image view.
viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, imageView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

/* the rest of your code here... */
}
```