# ScrollView.contentSize doesn't work on IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My project is using `ScrollView.contentSize`.

When I run it on Simulator (iOS 8) it works fine.

But `ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize()` isn't working on iOS 7 on my own IPHONE 4.

It can be scrolled normally on IOS 8 (Simulator) but can't be scrolled on my IOS 7 (IPHONE 4).

This is my code:

```
self.scrollViewCovor.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollViewCovor.frame.width, height: 596 + 281 + 80)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what's happening?

Comment: It can be scrolled normally on IOS 8 (Simulator) but can't be scrolled on my IOS 7 (IPHONE 4)

Comment: The question is: _where_ is that code running?

Comment: Is your application under landscape mode?

Comment: No my app is  on portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIScrollView scrolls on all the simulators but not on my iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274492/uiscrollview-scrolls-on-all-the-simulators-but-not-on-my-iphone)

you just need to resize the scrollview's frame size in viewDidLayoutSubviews